# Ask a user to do an action before connecting to a Wifi router

Tags: wireless-router

Is there a way or a router that can ask every new user to do an action before connecting to the router, for example watching an ad video or filling a form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about "Captive Portal"... Some routers/AP for business come with this option... If you want to do it with a normal TP-Link ("for home") you can search a OpenWrt firmware...

I tried the captive portfal of fpSense for request name, email and phone to customers for create a little database...

In the case of fpSense, they provide you the lines of code for recognize the device and you can create a landing page, form or whatever you want... And about OpenWrt I never used it until now...

Comment: Can I use php for serverside validation  ?

Comment: You can use anything what you want in the server side... But checking the fact of use AJAX for send-receive the info and show if success or an error message.